# Could the word shem (שם) means anything other as ‘name’?

Tags: names, grammar-dikduk, shemos-sacred-names, shemot-exodus

Shemot 6:3 reads: “And I appeared to Avraham, to Yitzchak,
and to Ya'akov, by the name of God Almighty (El Shaddai), but
by My name, the Lord (the Tetragrammaton/Shem Hameforash) I was not known to them.” Or at least that is how it is usually translated.

A translation such as this seems to imply/suggests that the one who was previously known by the name of El Shadai will now be known by the name of the Tetragrammaton).

Therefore I wondered if the word 'name' (שם) should not be understood as 'title/description' like a noun?! In Hebrew grammar, the word ‘shem’ means a ‘noun.’ In that case God would be called God in the same way as Adam is called Adam (or should it be understood in the way Shem is called Shem).

Comment: shem means a number of things including "reputation" or "rank."

Comment: Related: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=chCzWp1wxak&ab_channel=ToviaSinger on exactly this question